# Shorten Array in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to shorten an array so it only contains 30 elements. If for example I have an array of 100 elements is it possible to take it and chop of (as to speak) 70 of those elements?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Use  [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to extract the range of elements you need.**

```
$short_array = array_slice($my_big_array, 0, 30)
```

`$short_array` will have first 30 elements of `$my_big_array`

Answer (score 10):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Usage:

```
$shortarray = array_slice($longarray, 0, 30);
```

Comment: @Gordon: sorry, I added an example.